# Step into .net framework System.Web, 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, system.web

Is anyone able to successfully load symbols for the 4.0 version of System.Web in Visual Studio 2010? I have seen many tutorials on this but am not able to find symbols that will work. The symbols from the Microsoft symbol servers do not work and are stripped down (very small size). The symbols I get from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx seem to be the right size but do not seem to match.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the [Full version of .Net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17851) installed on your machine, and not just the client profile.

> Application developers who require features that are not included in the Client Profile should target the full .NET Framework 4 instead of the [Client profile](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24872).

Comment: I have the full version installed.